# How can I emit a message via socket inside express router

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to emit a message via socket.io .  I want to do it when a express router is called .

```
var express         =   require("express");
var app             =   express();
var http            =   require('http').Server(app);
var io              =   require('socket.io')(http);
var bodyParser      =   require("body-parser");
var router          =   express.Router();

router.route("/test").post(function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body)
    response = {"error" : false,"message" : "api worked"};
    /*I want to emit a message via socket here */
});


app.use('/',router);
app.listen(3010);
console.log("Listening to PORT 3010");
```

How can I do , I have seen a lot of example of using socket . But I couldn't find a way to do what I want . I have also checked  the following question . But I couldn't accomplish it

[How to use socket.io in express routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909778/how-to-use-socket-io-in-express-routes)

Comment: Emit a message to who?  To what user?  To all connected users?  Or to the one that made the current request?

Comment: Technically what I want to do is , I want to create an api  as an example "example.com/test" . When user will call the api , I want to send a push notification to my android app .  So in my case I want to send message to all user .

Comment: `io.emit("someMsg", someData)` will send to all connected users.  Your clients will, of course, need to connect on socket.io in order to receive the message.

Comment: Well let me give it a try

Comment: Are you sending to all the connected channels at same time or each channel individually? I am not sure about that part but `io.emit(<channel>, <data>)` will do your job.

Comment: @SriHarshaKappala - socket.io does not have channels.  It has rooms and namespaces, but your recommendation is not how you send to either of those.  `io.emit("someMsg", someData)` sends a message to each client that is connected to the default or root namespace.

Comment: #offtop @jfriend00 are you socket.io team member? recently notice you answer a lot socket questions

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly - Not a team member, I just answer a lot of node.js questions of all types.

Comment: #offtop @jfriend00 which chat rooms you visit most? I'm kinda chatty

Comment: @shuvro what does mean __I couldn't accomplish it__ it's pretty simple, what's the problem

Comment: @jfriend00 it worked , thanks ! , would you please post your comment as answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer since it worked for you.

```
io.emit("someMsg", someData);
```

will send to all connected users. Your clients will, of course, need to be connected with socket.io in order to receive the message.