# Emit to specific person by socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, passport.js, steam

I'm using socket.io and passport.js to authenticate people with their Steam accounts. I want to be able to send data to specific Steam's ID. I'am alredy using

```
io.use(function(socket, next) {
     session(socket.handshake, {}, next);
});
```

to access passport data of passport inside socket.io. I've thought of of storing active sockets in array, then just find one with a proper Steam ID. Is there some better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var steamUsers= {};

io.sockets.on("connection",function(socket){
   //from passport
   socket.steamid= steamid;

   //store socket for every user
   steamUsers[socket.steamid] = socket;

   //emit from their socket
   steamUsers[steamid].emit('private',{msg:"private message"});
});
```

you shoude use this inside express routes. Getting data and emitting within express routes is tricky. Follow this link to setup socket.io inside express routes [How to use socket.io in express routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909778/how-to-use-socket-io-in-express-routes)